# Spinner in Scala Swing

Tags: swing, scala, spinner

How to do that:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html
using that: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#package ?

Comment: I think you meant to specify the swing package in yuor link: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.swing.package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wondering how to add a `JSpinner` to a Scala swing application, you need to use Component.wrap(JComponent) to get a Scala component.  This should give you something to model on:

```
import swing._

import javax.swing.SpinnerListModel
import javax.swing.JSpinner

object SpinnerDemo extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  val monthStrings: Array[Object] = Array("January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December")

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Spinner Demo"

    val monthModel = new SpinnerListModel(monthStrings)
    val spinner = new JSpinner(monthModel)
    contents = new FlowPanel {
      contents += new Label("Month")
      contents += Component.wrap(spinner)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy.

```
[error] /home/ciembor/projekty/VirtualCut/src/main/scala/View/View.scala:22: reference to Action is ambiguous;
[error] it is imported twice in the same scope by
[error] import javax.swing._
[error] and import swing._
```

`swing` and `javax.swing` are conflicting. I think I should import only `JSpinner` class.

Comment: Interesting.  The code in my answer compiled and ran correctly for me using scala 2.9.0.  I'll edit my answer and make the imports a little tighter.